# Creating a record with Associations - Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, activeadmin

I am using active admin and seem to be struggling with creating a record with an association. I have set this up in the normal way

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :member
attr_accessible :membership_type

end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :membership
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :membership
 attr_accessible :membership_attributes, :forename, :middlename, :surname, :house_no, :house_name, :street, :town, :postcode, :home_tel, :mobile_tel, :work_tel, :email

end
```

I then want to create a New member along with their membership type in the same form, so my member.rb looks like this so far

```
ActiveAdmin.register Member do
# Set Which Columns are to be displayed on the index page
index do
column :forename
column :middlename
column :surname
column :house_no
column :house_name
column :street
column :town
column :postcode
column :home_tel
column :mobile_tel
column :work_tel
column :email

column :membership do |member|
  member.membership.map{ |ms| ms.membership_type}
end

default_actions
end
# Set Which Columns are to be displayed on Create New Member
form do |f|
 f.inputs "Member Registration" do
 f.input :forename
 f.input :middlename
 f.input :surname
 f.input :house_no
 f.input :house_name
 f.input :street
 f.input :town
 f.input :postcode
 f.input :home_tel
 f.input :mobile_tel
 f.input :work_tel
 f.input :email
 end
  f.inputs :for => [:membership, f.object.membership || Membership.new] do |m|
   m.input :membership_type, :label => 'Membership Type', :as => :select, :collection => Membership.all.map{|m| [m.membership_type]} 

end 
  f.actions
end

end
```

This displays a select box where i can choose from various Membership types, but i dont seem to be passing the correct value when creating the record,

This is an example of what is being posted

```
member[forename]:Name 1
member[middlename]:Name 2
member[surname]:Name 3
member[house_no]:1
member[house_name]:
member[street]:Test Street
member[town]:Test Town
member[postcode]:CF23 7BD
member[home_tel]:01633222222
member[mobile_tel]:07864582356
member[work_tel]:01633555555
member[email]:test@mail.com
membership_attributes"=>{"membership_type"=>"Student"}
commit:Create Member
```

This doesn't seem right does it? Also when i try and view the record

```
column :memberships do |member|
  member.memberships.map{ |ms| ms.membership_type}
end
```

I get the following mysql error

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'memberships.member_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `memberships`.* FROM `memberships`  WHERE `memberships`.`member_id` = 10
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction please or can anyone see where im going wrong?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `f.input :memberships` try this:

```
f.has_many :memberships do |pf|
    pf.input :membership_type
end
```

and close your member object fields like this

```
f.inputs "Member Registration" do
    f.input :forename
    f.input :middlename
    f.input :surname
    ...
end
```

So your form should look like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Member Registration" do
    f.input :forename
    f.input :middlename
    f.input :surname
    # .. the rest of your fields
  end
  f.has_many :memberships do |pf|
    pf.input :membership_type
  end
  f.actions
end
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to be working im afraid, i now have a button that links to nothing labelled "Member Registration", i think my relationship may be incorrect, should be a has_one ?

Comment: would you mind either copying or making a screenshot of your whole /admin/member.rb and your Member and MembershipType models? (you can inbox them to me if you want)

Comment: i have updated my question, but i have changed the relationship to a member has_one relationship, which i think is the correct logic

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the MySQL error, i think for the association to work you need to add the column member_id to the memberships table. You can create the migration with

```
rails g migration add_member_id_to_memberships member_id:integer
```

Then migrate with

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```